# State provider returning Blank ui-view

Tags: angularjs

I have stateProvider which works correctly in all states except in 'main.updateWine' when user clicks on button. I have registered click event on button icon in html and it wakes function wlc.updateWine in controller which call state with params. But as result I get blank state. i repeat, all other states are working fine except this. 
code below:

```
(function(){
angular
    .module("winesModule")
    .config(Config);

    function Config($stateProvider){
        $stateProvider
        .state("main.wines",{
            url:"/wines",
            templateUrl:"app/components/wines/wines.html",
            controller: "winesController",
            controllerAs: "wlc"
        })
        .state("main.addWine",{
            url:"/addWine",
            templateUrl:"app/components/wines/addWine.html",
            controller:"addWine",
            controllerAs:"wAw",
            resolve:{
                wine:function(){
                    return{};
                }
            }
        })
/* THIS STATE RETURNS BLANK VIEW*/
        .state("main.updateWine",{
            url:"/updateWine/:id",
            teplateUrl:"app/components/wines/addWine.html",
            controller:"addWine",
            controllerAs:"wAw",
            resolve:{
                wine:function($stateParams, winesService){
                    return winesService.get({id: $stateParams.id})
                }
            }
        });
    }
})();
```

//CONTROLLER:

```
function(){

angular
    .module("winesModule")
    .controller("winesController", winesController);

    function winesController(winesService, $state){
        var wlc = this;
        wlc.data = {};

        var onSuccessGet = function(response){          
            wlc.data.wines = response.results;  
        }
        var getWineList = function(){

                winesService.get().$promise.then(onSuccessGet);             
            }
        getWineList();

        wlc.updateWine = function(wine){

            $state.go("main.updateWine", {id : wine._id});
        }
    }

})();
```

//HTML -TEMPLATE app/components/wines/addWine.html

```html
<div class="container">
 <h2>Add Wine</h2>
   <form id="nameFG"  name="nameFG"  ng-submit="wAw.submitWine();" >
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="usr">Wine:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" ng-model="wAw.newWine.name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="usr">Year:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="year" name="year" ng-model="wAw.newWine.year">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="usr">Grapes:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="grapes" name="grapes" ng-model="wAw.newWine.grapes">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="usr">Country:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="country" name="country" ng-model="wAw.newWine.country">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="usr">Region:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="region" name="region" ng-model="wAw.newWine.region">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      
      <button type="submit" class="form-control btn-warning" id="region">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: No console error.

Comment: Looks like your `wineService` methods return an object with a promise, not the promise itself. I think you have to do `return winesService.get({id: $stateParams.id}).$promise` in your resolve

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your resolve with

```
wine: function($stateParams, winesService) {
    return winesService.get({id: $stateParams.id}).$promise;
}
```

Comment: worth noting that this is a known "bug" in angular-ui router where errors in `resolve` are not propagated to the console. Github issue here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/469

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help I have finally solved the issue.

I have retyped state which was causing the issue and now it works, still don't now the reason, and what was different.

```
    .state("main.updateWine",{
            url: "/updateWine/:id",
            templateUrl:"app/components/wines/addWine.html",
            controller:"addWine",
            controllerAs:"wAw",
            resolve: {
                wine:function($stateParams, winesService){
                    return winesService.get({id: $stateParams.id});
                }
            }
        });
```